# Stopped earning reputation at 313 due to reputation cap, even though I have 9 accepted answers

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I am really confused about the reputation cap.

If I have 9 accepted answers, the cap should be at 335, but mine stopped at 313. I know I have an unaccept, but even so, it should be at 320.

Maybe it was the removal of a user, but if so, along with the unaccept, the cap should be 310.

Is there something I didn't get?

This is of course not the only time I wondered about this. Each time I'd search for a reason, but couldn't find one.

My `/reputation` audit for today:

```
 1  62629395 (15)
 2  62629395 (10)
 1  62629077 (15)
 2  62630943 (10)
 2  62631155 (10)
 2  62631155 (10)
 2  62631155 (10)
 3  62618274 (-2)
 2  62628855 (10)
 3  62543008 (-1)
 3  57591656 (-1)
 3  62640352 (-2)
 2  62640352 (10)
 1  62640352 (15)
 3  62010259 (-2)
 2  62640843 (10)
 1  62640843 (15)
 2  62640969 (10)
 2  62640352 (10)
 2  62642155 (10)
 3  62626810 (-2)
 3  62629274 (-2)
 2  62644609 (10)
 2  62644609 (10)
 2  62644884 (10)
 2  62645116 (10)
 2  62645116 (10)
 1  62645116 (15)
 3  62646012 (-2)
 2  62646378 (10)
 2  62646378 (10)
 2  62646378 (10)
 1  62645962 (15)
 2  62646378 (10)
 2  62646378 (10)
 1  62646012 (15)
 1  62646378 (15)
 2  62646875 [4]
 2  62648238 [0]
 1  62648238 [15]
-- 2020-06-29 rep +335  = 7951
```

Comment: Go to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and paste the content for today into this question. Occasionally, the reputation displayed on the site may be slightly inaccurate as it is cached; this will calculate and output the correct total for your reputation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As your full reputation history from the `/reputation` page shows, you've earned 335 reputation from votes cast *today*, not including reversals of votes cast prior to today. This is equal to 200 capped reputation plus 9 accepted answers times 15 reputation, as you point out. This leaves a deficiency of -22 points.

Going through your reputation history on your profile, it seems that you lost a total of 25 reputation from reversals of votes cast on *prior* days. (These reversals aren't shown in the `/reputation` audit page; that'll instead show your prior days' history as if the votes were never cast.) This includes -15 from an unaccepted answer, and -10 from a prior upvote that was removed due to a user removal.

The above explains a -25 deficiency between what you earned from votes today and your overall net reputation gain, but as you can see, there are 3 extra points missing. I was initially scratching my head as to where those came from, but then I saw in your reputation audit here that your total rep should only be 7,951, but your profile on the site says 7,954. It seems that your site profile is inconsistently adding 3 reputation. The most common cause of this is if you [downvoted answers but removed your downvote on a day you hit the reputation cap](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352454/2157772):

> If you go to [your] /reputation audit you'll see your rep didn't actually go up. There is some heavy caching going on on your daily rep that has some edge-case issues (bugs), and undoing a downvote after the rep-cap is one of them.

To summarize, you gained 335 reputation from votes today, but lost 25 reputation from reversals of votes cast on prior days. The extra 3 is there because of heavy caching of reputation on the system's end.

Comment: If i hit the cap, then there was some reversal upvotes, am I still at the cap?

Comment: @AnnZen Yes. When a vote is removed, it's as if your vote was never cast on the day it was cast.

Comment: So if i earn 200 from accepts, then 200 from upvotes, and all the upvotes were reversed, I cannot gain anymore rep from upvotes that day?

Comment: @AnnZen If the same votes from *the same day* were reversed, you can earn more rep. But if upvotes from *prior days* were reversed, you can't earn any more rep. (The rep from accepts is irrelevant as it's completely exempt.)

Comment: So, tldr **it was caching, like always.**