# Why wasn't this upvote counted toward rep?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

Why wasn't this upvote counted toward rep?

[image]

Screenshot from https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/178179/franck-dernoncourt?tab=reputation

Comment: The removed upvote was probably from a prior day, so even though it displays on that page as affecting that later day's reputation, as far as the system's concerned, you've earned 200 rep that day and the lost rep is from the day the vote originally occurred. If you go to your `/reputation` log, it will show you earned 200 rep on that day. Check there and see if that's the case.

Comment: If that is the case, then [I have a rep to protect. Where is it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262031/i-have-a-rep-to-protect-where-is-it) answers your question. (The case there is slightly different, about a removed user, but the same thing applies whether a vote is removed manually by a user or automatically due to user deletion.)

Comment: See also [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350163/stopped-earning-reputation-at-313-due-to-reputation-cap-even-though-i-have-9-ac), which is a bit more of a complicated case since they had a bunch of accepted answers and an unrelated caching error was also affecting the count, but was the same root cause.

Comment: It's supposed to always be correct: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123319/282094

Comment: I voted to close (hope it wasn't a mistake), but I like this question better than the dup target, because it lacks a screenshot.